# replace RHS of rule

Tags: replacement, rule

is there an elegant way of replacing the RHS of a rule with the value of some function of it. Say I have `{{a -> 1.2}, {a -> 2.3}}` and I want to replace `1.2` with `Sqrt[1.2]` and `2.3` with `Sqrt[2.3]`? I know it can be done by pulling out the values, applying the function and building a new list of rules but this doesn't look very nice.

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: `MapAt[Sqrt, {{a -> 1.2}, {a -> 2.3}}, {;; , 1, 2}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ReplaceAll`.

```
{{a -> 1.2}, {a -> 2.3}} /. ({lhs_ -> rhs_} -> {lhs -> Sqrt[rhs]})
(* {{a -> 1.09545}, {a -> 1.51658}} *)
```

You can get fancier on the selection rule by changing or conditioning the pattern.

Comment: great, thank you so much.

Comment: I'd use `:>`. You never know what lives in ``Global` `` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = {{a -> 1.2}, {a -> 2.3}} 
Normal /@ Sqrt /@ Association /@ lst
```

> {{a -> 1.095445}, {a -> 1.516575}}

More generally,

```
Normal /@ Map[foo] /@ Association /@ lst
```

> {{a -> foo[1.2]}, {a -> foo[2.3]}}